# Match multiple columns over multiple sheets?

Tags: excel

```
Sheet1
qwerty,1234
asdf,2345
zxcv,3456

Sheet2
uiop,0987
qwerty,6789
qwerty,1234
fghjk,4567
zxcv,3456
zxcv,7890
```

How to highlight the row in `Sheet1` iff `Sheet2` have at least 1 row that matches both columns? In this example, the rows `qwerty,1234` and `zxcv,3456` should be highlighted.

I need both data to be on the same row to match.

`=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A:$A,1,FALSE)))` matches only 1 column, how to do it for both?

Comment: Use COUNTIFS for this.

Comment: @BigBen How to do that?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!A:A,A1,Sheet2!B:B,B1)>0`.

Comment: @BigBen How do I match if I need both data to be on the same row?

Comment: `COUNTIFS` looks for a match on the same row. Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Match()` function like below. But `COUNTIFS()` would be best as it will be faster.

```
=MATCH($A1&$B1,Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5&Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5,0)
```

[image]